# Service worker not working for Chrome

Tags: javascript, php, google-chrome, service-worker

Service worker gets registered but `navigator.serviceWorker.ready` showing null.

```
navigator.serviceWorker.register('sw.js', {scope: './'}).then(function(registration) {
  // Registration was successful
  console.log('ServiceWorker registration successful with scope: ',    registration.scope);
    //Check subscription state
    checkSubscription();
    });
})
function checkSubscription() {
console.log('fun checkSubscription');
navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(function(serviceWorkerRegistration){
serviceWorkerRegistration.pushManager.getSubscription().then(
  function(pushSubscription) {
    if(!!pushSubscription) {
      console.log(pushSubscription);
      pushStatus = true;

    }
    else {
      pushStatus = false;
     }
  }.bind(this)).catch(function(e) {
    console.error('Error getting subscription', e);
  });
});
}
```

Above is my code. This is working fine in Firefox browser.

Comment: what error you get in chrome. check console and let us know

Comment: `//sw.js
self.addEventListener('activate', function(event) {
    console.log("SW activated");
});
`

Comment: no error in chrome

Comment: above is code of SW.js

Comment: https://jakearchibald.com/2014/using-serviceworker-today/

Answer (score 0):

if runing service worker on Google Chrome, you need run your website on server like apache (xampp) / nodejs (http-server).

Comment: I am trying with this code and running with "npm run server" so data is showing now but error is still same